# can you run half a script in bash and the other half in expect

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp, expect

Im trying to make a script to automate ssh login and download of a file for multiple ip addresses that are kept in a file, im using a `for i in $(cat /dir/file)`, problem is the cat function is working in expect so i cant use it on a script that is interpreted with expect.
I wanted to know if it is possible to make half of the script be interpreted by bash and the other half by expect like this

```
#!/bin/bash
code........
#!/usr/bin/expect
code........
```

my code now looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
expect <<-EOF
    spawn sftp user@server
    expect "*password:" { send "password\r" }
    expect "*" { send "get /home/file\r" } 
    expect "*" { send "bye\r" }
EOF
```

i get this response now

```
spawn sftp user@server
user@server´s password: user@hostname: /home/user
```

basically it return to the normal terminal state

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: Technical answer - no. Practical answer - `bash` can invoke `expect`, so sure. See Bayou's solution, below.

Comment: For shell heredocs, you **must not** use leading whitespace for the heredoc terminator: remove the spaces before "EOF"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Heredoc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) might be the solution for you. I haven't used `expect` before, so it might seem a little buggy, but the following script works:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=user
SERVER=server
read -sp "password: " PASSWORD

expect <<-EOF
        spawn ssh ${USER}@${SERVER}
        expect "*: "
        send "${PASSWORD}\r"
        expect "*$ "
        send "ls\r"
        expect "*$ "
        send "exit\r"
EOF
exit $?
```

The keywords here are `<<-EOF` and `EOF`. The code in between is executed by `expect`.

EDIT: 
Note that `sftp` only works when you expect `*>`. The string `*` is too broad, which causes `expect` to react to premature text (e.g. motd, "Connected to server.", etc).

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=user
SERVER=server
read -sp "password: " PASSWORD

expect <<-EOF
        spawn sftp ${USER}@${SERVER}
        expect "* " { send "${PASSWORD}\r" }
        expect "*> " { send "get derp\r" }
        expect "*> " { send "bye\r" }
EOF
exit $?
```

Comment: this is doing something wierd, im pretty sure that the here docs is making the send commands write to my terminal and not having them interpreted by the expect. For example if in the line after the spawn if i put  expect "*" { send "${PASSWORD}\r } 
, it just prints my password to the terminal so it looks like this  spawn ssh user@${server} ; $PASSWORD  , and if i have it / expect "password:" / ,it just writes the  spawn  function to my terminal but doesn't actually execute it

Comment: I've tested the script on my Debian 9 laptop with Bash 4.4.12. When you copy the script 1-on-1, does it work for you? Maybe if you update the question with your code, I can see what's wrong :-)

Comment: Note this crucial bit of information: when using `<<-EOF`, any leading whitespace for the "EOF" terminator **must** be `Tab` characters. In this case there is no leading whitespace for "EOF" but with "<<-EOF", tabs are allowed.

Comment: As &Glenn correctly noticed, the ‘EOF’ should be at the beginning of the line. Remove the leading withespaces before ‘EOF’and I’m almost certain your code will work. However, the ‘expect’ code works with either 8 leading spaces or a tab. (I’ve tested it some hours ago, will look into it later).

Comment: I get a different weird error now ive updated the description

Comment: I think it's because `expect` reacts to premature sftp output. I'll update my answer one last time, but this is kind of out of scope ;-)

Comment: @Letho123, would you please accept my answer along with the answers you've gotten in other threads from other users, if you feel we answered your questions correctly? :-)