# How to write a string containing private ssh key to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am using Azure DevOps for my pipeline. For testing purposes, I have created a variable $key to store the private key. I want to use that key to SSH to a remote server. When I try to write the $key to a file and then use it e.g.

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 -i keyfile
```

I get asked for a passphrase. I believe that this is to do with the format of the private key file. It appears as a long string without line breaks.

What is the best way to format the string and write it to a .pem file?

Comment: you might want to launch an ssh-agent, add the key, and manually enter the passphrase. You only need to do this once, then you don't have to provide the key for your ssh sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Glen. I'm trying to automate it with Azure DevOps. The key needs to be installed on the build server from a variable (for now) so I can't interact with the session.

Comment: Then you'll want to create a new key with no passphrase.

Comment: They key does not have a passphrase. I am storing the key text as a variable and creating a file from that variable. I think it is the format of the file that is incorrect i.e. there aren't any line breaks. I'm looking to find out how to format a private key created from a string correctly with line breaks included.

Comment: I see. I don't know what the format of a private key file has to be specifically. You might try generating a key with ssh-keygen and example the created private key file with what you need to create.

Comment: Also, ssh is very particular about the permisisons of that file. It must be read-write only to you. And perhaps the directory needs to be read-write-execute only to you.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the permissions. It looks like a formatting issue

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while ServerFault covers admin questions and AskUbuntu covers general questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make use of private keys, you should add your public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh you@server 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa you@server
```

Please note that you should allow sshd to login via public key:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

If you can't change the settings on the server, you might want to make use of `expect`. It less secure, tho. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183907/can-you-run-half-a-script-in-bash-and-the-other-half-in-expect/56185735#56185735) for more information.